# How to make a button as default on its keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="srcSchtext" class="form-control" 
        runat="server" placeholder="Search here..." />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearchEmployee" 
            Text="Search" class="btn btn-info"  />
    </span>
</div>
```

...

```
function OnEnter_press(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        $('[id$=btnSearchEmployee]').click();
        return true;
    }
}
```

whenever I enter text in the textbox and click enter the page is just post backing, every time I have to take my mouse cursor to the button and click it for results. On enter press inside the text box I've to get the search results rather than just postbacking. I tried calling OnEnter_press on keydown of text box, which is still making just the postback.

Comment: default for what? do you often run across buttons that trigger OTHER buttons when you push them? e.g. click A but have the button B action occur?

Comment: I've updated the question, let me know If I'm not clear

Comment: Forms containing a single input will submit automatically when enter is pressed in this input.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an onclick event on that keydown something like this:

```
<input type="button" onkeydown="myFunction()">
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted my question here which didn't work, please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a button as default on its keydown?

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use **Panel** control's **[DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key inside the **Textbox**, **btnSearchEmployee_Clic** will fire at server side.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="input-group" 
    DefaultButton="btnSearchEmployee">
    <input type="text" id="srcSchtext" class="form-control"
        runat="server" placeholder="Search here..." />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearchEmployee"
            Text="Search" class="btn btn-info" 
            OnClick="btnSearchEmployee_Click" />
    </span>
</asp:Panel>
```